# Custom signature breaking read only lock on acroform fields on iPad only (PDFTron)

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdftron, pdfnet

When adding a custom signature to a PDF document I set all form fields to read only. This works perfectly on iPhone but on iPad something strange happens. The form fields are not set to read only but instead the touch handler sees them as signature fields and when clicked/touched they display the signing dialogue.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you please confirm which version of PDFNet you are on. [PTPDFNet GetVersion]. Also, this happens with every PDF document you try, with fields, or only certain ones. Finally, how are you setting the fields to read only? Please post code for that.

Comment: Hi Ryan, PDFNet ver: 48755554l. This happens on all PDFs which have form fields.
PTPDFDoc *pdfDoc = [m_pdfViewCtrl GetDoc];
    PTFieldIterator *itr = [pdfDoc GetFieldIterator];
    for(; [itr HasNext]; [itr Next]) {
        PTFieldType type = [[itr Current] GetType];
        if(type == e_ptchoice || type == e_ptcheck || type == e_ptbutton || type == e_ptradio || type == e_pttext) {
            NSLog(@"flatten");
            [[itr Current] SetFlag:e_ptread_only value:YES];
        } else if (type == e_ptsignature) {
            NSLog(@"Field SIG do nothing");
        }
    }

Comment: In any case I patched it up with an if statement and introducing a variable..far from elegant but need to release..

Comment: Glad you found a work around, though we would really like to help you resolve the issue. Are you on Xamarin.iOS? When the fields get treated incorrectly as signature field, is this with our viewer? Or a 3rd party viewer?

Comment: Thanks. We are using your Obj-C library for native iOS development. And using your default viewer. Now there are 2 types of sigs that we are supporting: Sigs imbedded in the pdf by the creator and sigs that the users adds manually and drags into position. The former works perfectly on both pad and phone. As soon as I add a 'manual' sig the viewer started recognising the read only form fields as sig fields on the pad only.

Comment: Could you post the code showing how you "add a manual sig"